# An error during using graph_frozen.pb in invoke_stepperr of tfdbg

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow

OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04): Linux Ubuntu 16.04.1

TensorFlow installed from (source or binary): binary

TensorFlow version (use command below): tensorflow-gpu (1.1.0)

Python version: 2.7.12

I use this command to frozen my graph and wights:

```
python -m tensorflow.python.tools.freeze_graph \
--input_graph ./rnn_graph.pb \
--input_checkpoint ./model.ckpt-320000 \
--output_graph ./graph_frozen.pb \
--output_node_name=rnn_model_20/softmax_output \
--input_binary=true
```

I used graph_frozen.pb in another program. And I got a right result. But when I used tfdbg and invoke_stepper model, I got a very strange error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: A cross-device loop must have a pivot predicate
```

Why there is a error but I can get a right answer? I can not find the same problem on the Internet. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?
Thanks in advance.